# What's wrong with my router?

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection

We recently bought a new router, a Sitecom 300N, to replace a broken one. It worked for about a week but now the internet pretty much gone, I can rarely get a page to load.

I can ping the router's IP address fine. However if I try to ping a remote host, our default gateway, or the modem itself, and for all I get similar packet loss rates of about 70%. this suggests to me that the problem lies between the modem and the router. I've tried connecting a different router to the modem, but that works fine.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried a different cable between the router and the modem? Have you tried resetting it? Have you tried super-resetting it (restoring to factor defaults)?

Comment: If both the router and the modem have IP addresses, that almost definitely means you have double-NAT set up. If your router is doing NAT, your modem should be in bridge mode.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try to see if you can change the negotiation and speed settings on the interface that talks to the modem. I'm guessing that the auto-negotiation is not working properly causing the interface to flap.  On the administrative console try hard coding the interface settings and see if there is a combination between the 100/10 speed and half/full duplex settings that resolves the issue.  You can also try and troubleshoot this issue with the ISP as they maybe able to change those settings on the modem as well.  Hope this helps!

Comment: +1  Have seen this fairly often lately and it is not well documented in the manuals